# WPF UserControl doesn't work with DependencyProperty OnSomeBytePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

To start, I have made an `UserControl` in a `WPF` project for setting colors in a settings window.

The Window has a ViewModel called `MainWindowViewModel.cs` containing:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace integrate.vsto.planning.settings.wpf.Viewmodels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Viewmodel used in the MainWindow
    /// </summary>
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region Fields (Border color)

        /// <summary>
        /// Red value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        private byte _borderColorR { get; set; } = 200;

        /// <summary>
        /// Green value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        private byte _borderColorG { get; set; } = 200;

        /// <summary>
        /// Blue value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        private byte _borderColorB { get; set; } = 200;

        #endregion

        #region Properties (Border color)

        /// <summary>
        /// Red value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        public byte BorderColorR
        {
            get { return _borderColorR; }
            set
            {
                _borderColorR = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorR));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorBrush));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Green value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        public byte BorderColorG
        {
            get { return _borderColorG; }
            set
            {
                _borderColorG = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorG));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorBrush));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Blue value (0-255) of the border color
        /// </summary>
        public byte BorderColorB
        {
            get { return _borderColorB; }
            set
            {
                _borderColorB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorB));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColorBrush));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// WPF compatible color for any element containing an implementation for a Brush
        /// </summary>
        public Brush BorderColorBrush
        {
            get
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(BorderColorR, BorderColorG, BorderColorB));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        /// The event triggered on any Property changed
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires the PropertyChanged event for the given property (by name)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Given property name</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

This Viewmodel contains a lot more than the given code, and works fine for everything containing no user control interactions, like texts and other bytes presented in normal Textboxes. So the link between my MainWindow and the Viewmodel is properly setup like `this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();`

Then there is the UserControl called `ColorSettingUserControl`

```cs
using integrate.vsto.planning.settings.wpf.Viewmodels;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace integrate.vsto.planning.settings.wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ColorSettingUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ColorSettingUserControl : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The viewmodel for the color settings user control
        /// </summary>
        private ColorSettingViewModel _viewmodel;
    
        #region Attribute Registry

        /// <summary>
        /// The red value (0-255) for the preview control
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Red), typeof(byte), typeof(ColorSettingUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((byte)0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnRedPropertyChanged))

        /// <summary>
        /// The green value (0-255) for the preview control
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GreenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Green), typeof(byte), typeof(ColorSettingUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((byte)0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnGreenPropertyChanged))

        /// <summary>
        /// The blue value (0-255) for the preview control
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BlueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Blue), typeof(byte), typeof(ColorSettingUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((byte)0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnBluePropertyChanged))

        #endregion

        #region Attribute Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Color value red (0-255)
        /// </summary>
        public byte Red
        {
            get { return (byte)GetValue(RedProperty); }
            set { _viewmodel.Red = value; SetValue(RedProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Color value green (0-255)
        /// </summary>
        public byte Green
        {
            get { return (byte)GetValue(GreenProperty); }
            set { _viewmodel.Green = value; SetValue(GreenProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Color value blue (0-255)
        /// </summary>
        public byte Blue
        {
            get { return (byte)GetValue(BlueProperty); }
            set { _viewmodel.Blue = value; SetValue(BlueProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the XAML lines in the UserControl that I need to work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="integrate.vsto.planning.settings.wpf.ColorSettingControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:integrate.vsto.planning.settings.wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <TextBox x:Name="txt_R" Text="{Binding Red}" Width="46" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_G" Text="{Binding Green}" Width="46" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_B" Text="{Binding Blue}" Width="46" />

</UserControl>
```

And then the XAML for the MainWindow's implementation of the UserControl

```cs
<local:ColorSettingUserControl
    Red="{Binding BorderColorR}" 
    Green="{Binding BorderColorG}" 
    Blue="{Binding BorderColorB}" />
```

So I don't get the actual value of `BorderColorR` from the MainWindow's Viewmodel into the user's control Textbox. When debugging, the debugger also won't stop in the setter of public byte Red, nor the Green or Blue ones.

Not sure in what direction I need to do my research to make this work.

###### What I tried

I have looked at other questions related to this issue. However, I can't find the proper resource to investigate my issue. Everything works when entering a value directly in the `<ColorSettingUserControl Red="20" />`, and when I just make a new `<Label Text={Binding Red} />` it gives the red color from the ViewModel. But when doing `<ColorSettingUserControl Red={Binding Red}>` it doesn't work.

I tried to use `PropertyMetadata` instead of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` in `ColorSettingUserControl.cs` for the dependency properties.

When trying the value without a Binding, like `<ColorSettingUserControl Red="20" />`, it actually triggers the setter of the DependencyProperty.

###### What I expect

I expect that the `<ColorSettingUserControl Red={Binding BorderColorR} />` triggers the setter of the DependencyProperty, which has a default value in it's private declaration.

Comment: Your view model must not create any Brush objects. They must be created in the view.

Comment: There must also not be a private view model instance in the UserControl. Remove the `_viewmodel` field and all the assignments like `_viewmodel.Red = value;` etc. from the UserControl's code. The dependency property setter methods are not called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings inside the `UserControl` are wrong. They use the `DataContext` as data source what is wrong. They must use the `UserControl` as data source.

You achieve this by using `Bindig.RelativeSource` (or alternatively `Binding.ElementName` which performs better as it doesn't have to traverse the element tree and uses the static lookup table of the current name scope instead):

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">

  <!-- Option #1: Use Bindig.RelativeSource -->
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_R" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Red}" Width="46" />

  <!-- Option #2: Use Binding.ElementName -->
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_G" Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Green}" Width="46" />

    <TextBox x:Name="txt_B" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Blue}" Width="46" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I like the idea of having option #2 where you use ElementName=Root, Path=Red. Although I don't get the debugger to actually trigger the setter when using this Control in my MainWindow like `<ColorSettingUserControl Red={Binding SomeByteValue}>`, which still results in no value in the Textbox of the user control.

Comment: What is the ColorSettingViewModel instance doing in the UserControl?
 It looks like you are changing the DataContext of the UserControl internally which will always break any external bindings. You must never set the DataContext of a UserControl or custom control explicitly. Just remove the ColorSettingViewModel and the external bindings will work properly. Depending on what's inside the ColorSettingViewModel you want to move this code to the UserControl's code-behind.

Comment: Also MVVM does not mean that every control has its own view model. MVVM is an application-level design pattern and not UI level pattern to devel controls.

Comment: *"Although I don't get the debugger to actually trigger the setter"* - The setter of a dependency property is never called by the binding engine. It always uses the DependencyObject.SetValue method directly. That's why you should not add code to the setter and instead register the dependency property changed callback.

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite new to WPF as you noticed :D But these comments were really helpful

Comment: No problem. I'm happy if I helped you. I hope everything is working now. Just as a reminder: all WPF standard controls like the Button, ListBox, DataGrid etc. don't actively set their DataContext. If they need external data they expose dependency properties that we the client have to set.

Comment: The controls never directly use their DataContext. The DatContext is meant for data binding. And also no framework controntrol comes with its own view model -  because the view model is the data provider for the view. In the view we send the data from the view model to the individual controls. The view uses view models but not individual controls. Controls display data. This data comes from the view model. Anything else that the control does is view business and belongs to the code-behind or other classes of the view.